# create two new pages, but it doesent show them

Tags: php

I have create 2 new pages faq.blades.php and about.blade.php

But when i tryed to see them it doesn't show them.

I only see : Page Not Found

meny in index.blade.php

```
<li><a href="about">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="faq">FAQ</a></li>
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel? Have you seen the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls

Comment: all other pages works, but not this 2

Comment: We don't enough information to help you. Are you using a framework? What is your directory structure setup like?

Comment: this is my login page: <li><a href="login">User Login</a></li> and it works like a charm... and i pages are located in resources\views

Comment: Niklas, you are clearly using a framework, is it Laravel or something like that ? If you tell us wee can be more helpfull to you :)

Comment: sorry, yes its laravel

Comment: Please show us the relevant section in your `routes/web.php` file where those routes are defined.

Comment: Normally, you'd use the `url()` helper (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url) in your Blade views. Ex. `<a href="{{ url('about') }}">About</a>` but it all depends how these routes are setup.

Comment: I add this to routes/web.php ... Route::get('/faq', function () {
    return view('faq');
});,  id did´t now i need to  do that..thanks for help.

Comment: Did the `url()` helper work?

Comment: no , i add only about and faq.

Answer (score 1):

Can your try this (If you are not using a framework) ? =>

```
<li><a href="about.blade.php">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="faq.blades.ph">FAQ</a></li>
```

Comment: Can you try with your actual url and replace index.php with about.blade.php ? <li><a href="http://localhost/myProject/about.blade.php">About us</a></li>

Comment: Niklas, you are clearly using a framework, is it Laravel or something like that ? If you tell us wee can be more helpfull to you :)

Answer (score 0):

> `Route::get('/faq', function () { return view('faq'); });`

Given your route, the blade code to link to this page is:

```
<a href="{{ url('faq') }}">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
```